# How to perform a regression analysis with time variable?

Tags: r, time, regression

I am doing regression analysis on stock shareholder amount to the stock's price volatility. My dataset spans one year and each month has one observation per company. How do I take this time change into account with my analysis?

I have an excel file imported to R (picture attached) with one column for "date" which has 12 different values (each representing last day of the month) and I would like to analyze how the change in shareholders from timepoint to another affects the stock volatility, which are my independent and dependent variables respectively.

Thank you for any piece of advice!

[image]

[image]

I ran a regression analysis in R with the "model <- lm" code, but realized that R does not consider my time variable that way. I would like to have R to look at the change in Shareholders and Volatility from timepoint A to timepoint B and do a regression analysis of how much of the shareholders change is attributable to the volatility change.